# Removing some text in a title while scraping

Tags: python, string, scrapy

I am currently trying to scrapy a youtube playlist. 
The scrap works however I would like to get only a portion of the title.

**For example :**

- The video title is:

  > 'Et si on mangeait la connaissance? | Idriss Aberkane |
  >   TEDxPanthéonSorbonne'
- Through scraping I would like to get only:

  > 'Et si on mangeait la connaissance?'

I would like to delete all the characters after `|`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

p = re.compile("(.*?) \|.*")
m = p.search('Et si on mangeait la connaissance? | Idriss Aberkane | TEDxPanthéonSorbonne')
```

This gives your desired string:

```
m[1]
```

Comment: thank you !!! I tried in pipelines using regex and "/|.*" and it worked suppressing everything after the "|"

Answer (score 0):

If you sure about "|" character will be there in every title you can write something like this

```
string title = "test title | about anything";
string result ="";
if(title.indexOf("|") > -1)
    result = title.substring(0, test.indexOf("|"));
```

Comment: Oops you are right. Question was about pyhton ): how can I remove my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all content at first occurrence of '|' you can write below code:

```
scrap_result = 'Et si on mangeait la connaissance? | Idriss Aberkane | TEDxPanthéonSorbonne' # this is the scrap result of the title you get you can user str() to be precise so you only get string is a title.
scrap_result = scrap_result[:scrap_result.find("|")] # this will give you result before the first occurrence of '|' but it includes trailing space at the end if you want to remove it use scrap_result.strip()
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah it is possible you have two choices:
Slicing the string

```
String = 'Et si on mangeait la connaissance? | Idriss Aberkane | TEDxPanthéonSorbonne'
String = String[-1:-x]
```

Replacing:

```
String = String.replace(' | Idriss Aberkane | TEDxPanthéonSorbonne', '')
```